How do I sort a nested array of strings and objects based on predetermined array of just strings?
I already searched and could not find the answer.
let correct_order_arr = ["dsihdlepsn", "dxuwmcbdeu", "dqpoimndxcv", "dplaeitfvse", "drtbnmjhfw", "ddrnvuqasw", "dfpotbnmjk", "dauiopmvdf", "drvbumnbvc"]
let starting_array =    [[my_object_1,"dsihdlepsn"], [my_object_2,"dxuwmcbdeu"], [my_object_3,"dqpoimndxcv"], [my_object_4,"dplaeitfvse"], [my_object_5,"dfpotbnmjk"], [my_object_6, "drtbnmjhfw"], [my_object_7, "ddrnvuqasw"], [my_object_8, "dauiopmvdf"], [my_object_9, "drvbumnbvc"]];

let desired_arr = starting_array.sort(function (a,b){
   if (correct_order_arr[a] === starting_array[a][1]){
     return 0;
   } else {
    return 1;
   }
})

//desired_arr = [[my_object_1,"dsihdlepsn"], [my_object_2,"dxuwmcbdeu"], [my_object_3,"dqpoimndxcv"], [my_object_4,"dplaeitfvse"], [my_object_6, "drtbnmjhfw"], [my_object_7, "ddrnvuqasw"], [my_object_5,"dfpotbnmjk"], [my_object_8, "dauiopmvdf"], [my_object_9, "drvbumnbvc"]];


iterate through your "correct_order_arr" and pull from your starting array

Don't use sort for this. It's used when you need to compare the elements with each other to determine the relative order.
You just need to loop over correct_order_arr, and find the corresponding elements in starting_array.


let correct_order_arr = ["dsihdlepsn", "dxuwmcbdeu", "dqpoimndxcv", "dplaeitfvse", "drtbnmjhfw", "ddrnvuqasw", "dfpotbnmjk", "dauiopmvdf", "drvbumnbvc"]
let starting_array = [
  ["my_object_1", "dsihdlepsn"],
  ["my_object_2", "dxuwmcbdeu"],
  ["my_object_3", "dqpoimndxcv"],
  ["my_object_4", "dplaeitfvse"],
  ["my_object_5", "dfpotbnmjk"],
  ["my_object_6", "drtbnmjhfw"],
  ["my_object_7", "ddrnvuqasw"],
  ["my_object_8", "dauiopmvdf"],
  ["my_object_9", "drvbumnbvc"]
];

result_array = correct_order_arr.map(s => starting_array.find(el => el[1] == s));
console.log(result_array);



